# Permission denied when saving to internal storage

Tags: android, file-io, storage, internal

When saving the a file to internal storage, some people get this massage:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data.../MyFile (Permission denied)
```

What might be the problem?
I create my file like this:

```
FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput("MyFile", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); // Line to cause the exception
```

and context is my activity the is sent as a parameter to the save function (static function). Should I use some Activity.getBaseContext or something like that? Any ideas what might be the problem?

Comment: What is the `context` that you are using? Is the file literally `MyFile`, or is it something else?

Comment: The context is current active activity. I send that as a parameter to the function when saving the file.  The file name is "Service.bin".

Answer (score 2):

Are you missing permissions in your manifest...? You should have the following at the application level...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: It's the internal storage, phone memory, not SD card. And only a few gets the error (but I do have that permission as well)

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the exact same issue. In my case, my guess is that there was something locking the files because I couldn't delete some of them either.

I had to use adb shell and delete the whole directory (using rm -r) to get this working.

Are you using a simulator or a device? Which one? If you're using a simulator, maybe your cache partition is out of space. You can set "Cache partition size" parameter using AVD Manager.

For the record, I'm using the Galaxy Tab emulator from Samsung.

Comment: Can you tell me how you deleted the files stored in internal memory? I am trying to delete some, but showing me permission denied error. you can give answer in [my posted question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831648/android-delete-sms-completely-from-the-device-and-make-sms-non-recoverable)

Comment: It's real devices that gets the error. I can't reproduce it myself, just get error reports from users.