# Android - Delete SMS completely from the device and make SMS non recoverable

Tags: android, message, permission-denied

I want to delete all the sms from the mobile through my application.
Currently, I am deleting messages using below code.

```
    Uri uriSms = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uriSms,
            new String[] { "_id", "thread_id", "address","person", "date", "body" }, null, null, null);

        if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                long id = c.getLong(0);
                getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/" + id), null, null);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
```

I am able to delete messages from mobile.

But by using some recovery applications, they are restored.

I tried to remove it completely by deleting the file from path

"data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db"

But it gave me following permission denied error.

```
12-12 00:37:29.673: W/System.err(9724): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db (Permission denied)
```

How can I completely remove the messages from my device? Using some secure delete method?

Comment: If your device is rooted then you can remove mmssms.db.But I think once you delete the db you cannot store messages as the db is deleted permanently.Take a backup of the db and try it.

Answer (score 0):

you can't remove a file that's stored on another application sandbox (as com.android.providers.telephony) unless the device is rooted.